# How can I send coversion statistics to the Media Manager analytics server?

Tags: javascript, media-manager

If a webpage uses the SDL Media Manager HTML5 player to play a video distribution, the visitor could take an action like navigating to a banner which would count as a conversion.

How can the webpage or web application notify the Media Manager analytics server about this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion rate percentage in Media Manager is calculated by the number of Custom Events triggered on the media divided by the number of views multiplied by 100.

enable the custom events (in the video assets) and the Conversion rate is will raise on the count of the events.

Comment: Custom events defined on the timeline of the video and the player will trigger the custom events (JavaScript) while the video plays.

Does this mean that playing the video (no other visitor action like cliking a link) will increase the conversion rate?

Comment: Maybe this is a 2nd question, but what if a video has 2 events, will both affect the conversion?   


So in case all visitors watch the whole video the conversion will be 200%.   


Number of Custom Events triggered on the media / by the number of views * 100 = (2 events * x views) / x views * 100 = 200 %